# A proof that involves Torsion, curvature, and differentiation that equates to 0

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-writing, curvature

[image: Below is the problem I am trying to solve]

I know that I am supposed to write alpha = lambda*T + mu*N + v*B then differentiate then use the fact that {T,N,B} is a basis in R^3. I am just unsure how to write alpha as a combination using the given information. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the curve is on sphere, if you differentiate $ || \alpha (s) || = 1 $, you find $ T \cdot \alpha $, so $ \alpha(s) = n(s) N(s) + b(s) B(s) $ for some functions $ n(s), b(s) $.

Now, differentiating $ \alpha = n N + b B $, one finds $ \alpha' = T = n' N + n N' + b' B + b B' $. Using the frenet-serret equations to rewrite $N'$ and $B'$,
$$ T = (n' - b \tau) N - n \kappa T  + (b' + \tau n)B $$ 
So, dotting with $ T, N, B $ gives $ n = -\frac{1}{\kappa} $ and $ n' - b \tau = b' + \tau n = 0 $.
Now dividing $ n' - \tau b = 0 $ by $ \tau $ and differentiating gives:
$$
0=\left(\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right) n' \right)' - b' \\
=-\left(\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\kappa} \right)' \right)' + \tau n \\
=-\left(\left(\frac{1}{\tau}\right) \left(\frac{1}{\kappa} \right)' \right)' - \frac{\tau}{\kappa} 
$$

It's been a while since I thought about this stuff, so I have feeling I went in a few circles. But there is no other answer, so I'll leave it up to clean this one up.

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes complete sense!